# vscode: attach debugger to firefox

Tags: firefox, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to debug attaching to my firefox. My configuration is:

```
{
        "name": "Attach to Firefox",
        "type": "firefox",
        "request": "attach",
        "port": 6000,
        "pathMappings": [{
            "url": "https://localhost:3000/",
            "path": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }],
        "log": {
            "fileName": "${workspaceFolder}/log.txt",
            "fileLevel": {
                "default": "Debug"
            }
        }
    }
```

Breakpoints are not reached.

I'm running against the same issue.

Obviously, I started firefox with debug server enabled and vscode is connected to:

```
firefox -start-debugger-server
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

for me, you need firstly attach the remote FF debugger https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=firefox-devtools.vscode-firefox-debug
if it attached correctly, you will see red background on URL fields

than you need to prepare very simple config, for example in my case

```
  [...,
    {
        "type": "firefox",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch firefox against localhost",
        "url": "file:///home/admin/AngularProjects/JsMax/finished/index.html",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
```

also there are two main case for start JS with .html page - one of them is "open on live server" https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server-plus-plus and second case "open in default browser" https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=peakchen90.open-html-in-browser - in first case we use context menu on main editor windows, in second case on project three. First case working perfectly with Node.js, second case for vanilla JS.

In this case I use debugger with vanilla Javascript, so I click open on default browser, I see red background on URL (that mean FF controlled remotely) and you can enjoy to use debugger on VS code (what connected remotely to FF)

[image: Firefox remote debugging]

also there are two variables, you can set up it on about:config

```
 devtools.debugger.remote-enabled   true    
 devtools.chrome.enabled    true
```

or the same variables you can see on Firefox dev tools on setting tab (on the bottom of right column)

[image: Firefox tuning for remote debugger]

And, pay attention, if you want to debug JS only functions (without FF) you need of course absolutely another config (and installed Node.js), for example in my case

```
    {
        "type": "node",
        "name": "Run Current File",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/Basic/NullishAndChaining.js"
    }
```

[image: Debug functions with Node.js]